# How to change source of img using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I need to change the source of image if its width is less than 600px.
I created following script but it is not working.

```js
var sizewidth = window.innerWidth;
screensize();

function screensize() {
  if (sizewidth < 601) {
    document.getElementById('logotipo').src = "../imgs/image.png";
  }
}
```

What is wrong in it? Can someone help me correct it?

Comment: Can use media queries.

Comment: Yes, but i want use javascript to learn about this language

Comment: what's the error coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and I think its working fine. Maybe issue is the placement of your script file/code. Just check below

```js
var sizewidth = window.innerWidth;
screensize();

function screensize() {
  if (sizewidth < 601) {
    document.getElementById('logotipo').src = "../imgs/image.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="logotipo" src="logo.png">
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that the problem is in the location of script in my html.

Comment: @d3pod replace the function call `screensize();` for `window.onload=screensize;` this will ensure the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var sizewidth = window.innerWidth;
    screensize();
    function screensize() {
        if (sizewidth < 601) {
            document.getElementById('logotipo').setAttribute("src", "../imgs/image.png");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're using the OP's code, please indicate where you made the change. Otherwise the reader has to unnecessarily compare each line. Better yet, just paste the one line you made the change on and include a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path of your image is correct??(you can try looking for  console logs on your web browser) 
If yes then,try putting double \ in your code instead of \

Comment: What? *"try putting double \ in your code instead of \"* the OP doesn't have any backslashes in the source code? I think your approach to solving this is far from the actual issue. The source code functions just find if placed in the correct location on the page or placed within a window load function.